# Find a span without class id bs4?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to web scrape this page and I am trying to get the afternoon temp. How would I go about doing this as there are 4 other spans which are in the same class? For more information I am trying to get these 4 temperatures(circled)(First Link). The rest are the four times : morning, afternoon, evening, night. They all have the same class and same span and data-set-id so how would I use `soup.find` and and scrape the text in the span.

```
>https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhKVA.png
>https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubEuJ.png
>https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KLaX.png
>https://i.stack.imgur.com/LodTb.png
>https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0Pfb.png
```

my replit: https://replit.com/@HarshitJagarlam/DangerousSpitefulCopyright#main.py

```
<div data-testid="SegmentHighTemp" class="Column--temp--5hqI_"><span data-testid="TemperatureValue">22°</span></div>

<div data-testid="SegmentHighTemp" class="Column--temp--5hqI_"><span data-testid="TemperatureValue">27°</span></div>

<div data-testid="SegmentHighTemp" class="Column--temp--5hqI_"><span data-testid="TemperatureValue">20°</span></div>

<div data-testid="SegmentHighTemp" class="Column--temp--5hqI_"><span data-testid="TemperatureValue">15°</span></div>
```

Comment: Do you mind giving the url of the website?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your HTML and code as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

#### EDIT

Based on the url from one of your edits you can go with selecting the `<a>` that contains *Afternoon* an pick the first `<div>` with the `<span>`:

```
soup.select_one('a:-soup-contains("Afternoon")').div.span.text
```

###### Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

url = 'https://weather.com/en-GB/weather/today/l/7bc0022212d6873b8226ac81bad9714bc956aef8851519b045d7750eb3ea4745'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text)

soup.select_one('a:-soup-contains("Afternoon")').div.span.text
```

---

Select the outer `<div>` and its direct following `<span>` - by attribute `data-testid`:

```
soup.select_one('[data-testid="SegmentHighTemp"] > span')
```

or by `class`:

```
soup.select_one('div.Column--temp--5hqI_ > span')
```

or in combination of attributes:

```
soup.select_one('[data-testid="SegmentHighTemp"] > [data-testid="TemperatureValue"]')
```

**Note:** *this assumes that the `HTML` from the question is also present in the `soup` and is not dynamically generated via `JavaScript`.*

##### Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''
<div data-testid="SegmentHighTemp">
    <span data-testid="TemperatureValue">28°</span>
    <span data-testid="x">x</span>
    <span data-testid="y">y</span>
    <span data-testid="z">z</span>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.select_one('[data-testid="SegmentHighTemp"] > span').text
```

Comment: I am getting none in the console

Comment: How would i know if it is present in soup?

Comment: Simply print your soup and search for the part you expect - Edited my answer based on one of the urls you provided in your edits.

Comment: How would I go about doing this for Humidity? If I use your code and substitute 'div' instead of 'a' I get "none". How would I write the path at the end?

Comment: This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus - Hint:
`soup.select_one('.TodayDetailsCard--detailsContainer--16Hg0 div:-soup-contains("Humidity")').span.text`